# Average time between dates in two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, average

In our database, we've got a `coffee_types` table, and a `shipments` table.

Each coffee in `coffee_types` has a `roasted_at` date, each shipment has a `shipped_at` date.

I'd like to find the average between `roasted_at` and `shipped_at` for each coffee type, so this means making an average of all the `shipped_at - roasted_at` dates for each coffee.

How can I do this? The best I've managed is this, but it just gets the date difference per shipment:

```
SELECT coffee_types.name
     , date_part('day', age(coffee_types.roasted_at, shipments.shipped_at))
FROM coffee_types, shipments
WHERE coffee_types.id = shipments.coffee_type_id
GROUP BY coffee_types.name, coffee_types.roasted_at, shipments.shipped_at;
```

Comment: Can you paste the CREATE TABLE statements and a few INSERT statements for both tables?

Answer (score 1):

To get the "age" of each coffee shipment, just subtract the timestamps producing an `interval` - or if you actually have `date` columns (your secret), the subtraction produces a simple `integer`:

```
SELECT c.name, s.shipped_at - c.roasted_at AS time_passed
FROM   coffee_types c
JOIN   shipments    s ON s.coffee_type_id = c.id
GROUP  BY c.name;
```

You don't need the `age()` function for that. [Format the interval](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html) any way you like.

To get the average time passed between roasting and shipping, group by `name` only - or, to be precise, any UNIQUE (combination of) column(s) of the `coffee_types` table).
Do ***not*** group by columns you want to compute an average from - that was your basic mistake:

```
SELECT c.name, avg(s.shipped_at - c.roasted_at) AS avg_time_passed
FROM   coffee_types c
JOIN   shipments    s ON s.coffee_type_id = c.id
GROUP  BY c.name;
```